Trying to prove $\Vert x \Vert_0\le\Vert x \Vert \le(b-a+1) \Vert x \Vert_0$
I was solving a question in Functional Analysis:

Let $X=C^1([a,b] )$. For $x\in X$, let $\Vert x\Vert =\Vert x \Vert_\infty+\Vert x'\Vert_\infty $ and $\Vert x \Vert_0=|x(a)|+\Vert x'\Vert_\infty $. Then $\Vert .\Vert$ and $\Vert . \Vert_0$ are equivalent norms on $X$. In fact, for every $x\in X$, $$\Vert x \Vert_0\le\Vert x \Vert \le(b-a+1) \Vert x \Vert_0$$ the constant $(b-a+1)$ being the least possible. Also if $x\in X$, then there is a sequence $(p_n)$ of polynomials such that $\Vert x-p_n \Vert \to 0$

Here, my thought process is : It is enough to prove the inequlity to show the norms are equivalent. That's why i directly dive into proving the inequality $\Vert x \Vert_0\le\Vert x \Vert \le(b-a+1) \Vert x \Vert_0$. The first step $\Vert x \Vert_0\le\Vert x \Vert$ is pretty obvious. I am suffering with the last part $\Vert x \Vert \le(b-a+1) \Vert x \Vert_0$. I was trying in the following manner:
$$\frac{\Vert x \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert_0}=\frac {\Vert x \Vert_\infty +\Vert x' \Vert_\infty}{|x(a)|+\Vert x'\Vert_\infty}\le \frac {\Vert x \Vert_\infty +\Vert x' \Vert_\infty}{\Vert x'\Vert_\infty }\le \Vert \frac{x}{x'}\Vert_\infty+1.$$ At the last step, I know $\Vert \frac{x}{x'} \Vert$ will be bounded but how to bound it exactly by $(b-a).$ Even I was trying to apply Mean Value Theorem for it, but didn't get any fruitful consequence. Please help me.
Another confusion is at the second part of the problem where we have to show the sequence of polynomial is always available to approximate of any given element $x\in X$. So, is the only difference between this problem and the Stone-Weierstrass theorem : the norm on which we are working? Even if you happen to have any observations with the problem, please share them. It will be very helpful to expand my circle of knowledge. Thank you, beforehand.

Your inequalities have several problems.  Instead, go back to the inequality you want to show and subtract $|x'|\infty$ from both sides to find you just want to show $$|x|\infty \leq (b-a+1)|x(a)| + (b-a)|x'|\infty.$$ To this end, use the mean value theorem to show $$|x|\infty \leq |x(a)| + (b-a)|x'|_\infty$$

For any $t\in [a,b]$, using MVT, we get $x(t)=x(a)+x'(\eta)(b-a)$, for some $\eta\in [a,b]$. Then, $$\vert x(t) \vert = \vert x(a) \vert + \vert x'(\eta)(b-a) \vert \le \vert x(a) \vert + \vert x'(\eta) \vert (b-a)\le \vert x(a) \vert +\Vert x' \Vert_\infty (b-a) \implies \Vert x \Vert_\infty\le\vert x(a)\vert+\Vert x' \Vert_\infty(b-a) \implies  \Vert x \Vert \infty +\Vert x' \Vert\infty \le \vert x(a)\vert +\Vert x' \Vert_\infty +\Vert x'\Vert_\infty(b-a) \implies \Vert x \Vert \le \Vert x\Vert_0 +\Vert x' \Vert_\infty(b-a)\le \Vert x \Vert_0(b-a)+\Vert x \Vert_0 $$.

@BrianMoehring, I think the above implications resolve the inequality problem a little bit. Thanks to you!!! But, how can we say that the bound $(b-a+1)$ is the least possible? I am clueless about this statement.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776189/1118406

@Pro_blem_finder Your steps in the comment still aren't careful enough (some are wrong).  If you are careful writing out the steps, you will be able to ask what the condition on $x$ would be for each $\leq$ to actually be $=$.  Then it's just a matter of finding such a function (sometimes this step can be quite hard, but in your case, it's quite a simple class of functions)

@BrianMoehring, Yes, I have committed some mistakes. I will correct them. I followed your way and there are some conditions we can impose followed by the conditions of equality, we can take a linear function and work with it. Hope I have said it correctly. Thank you, beforehand.

More particularly, we will take the straight line passing through origin.@BrianMoehring
